# Cross join between arbitrary number of sets

Tags: c#

in C# how can I create a cross join between an arbitrary number of sets?

E.g. given the following data:

```
var a = new[] { "1.1", "1.2" };
var b = new[] { "2.1", "2.2", "2.3" };
var c = new[] { "3.1" };
var sets = new[]{a,b,c};
```

I need the following output:

```
var expected = new[]
{
    new[]{"1.1", "2.1", "3.1"},
    new[]{"1.1", "2.2", "3.1"},
    new[]{"1.1", "2.3", "3.1"},
    new[]{"1.2", "2.1", "3.1"},
    new[]{"1.2", "2.2", "3.1"},
    new[]{"1.2", "2.3", "3.1"}
};
```

Comment: With linq? or pure C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi LINQ preferably but it's not important

Comment: @PeterCsala `SelectMany`, but that doesn't work with an arbitrary number of sets.

Comment: In code, you can do this with an array of iterators the same length as `sets`. The lowest order iterator goes from beginning to end of `c` then the next lowest-order iterator is advanced one position in `b`. If the 2nd-to-last is also at the end then next iterator in order is advanced one position, etc, etc. I suspect an recursive function will be easiest to implement but I would definitely have some unit tests for this. I don't have a C# compiler to write the solution now.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto For a finite number of input sets `SelectMany` is normally how you do cross joins, e.g. `a,SelectMany(x => b.SelectMany` atc.

Comment: I deleted my comment since I had missed the "arbitrary" part :)